# attr.style is not working in angular2 rc1

Tags: javascript, angular

I have upgraded from Angular2 beta to RC1

attr.style is not working properly, there is no error but this style is not coming

```
<div class="hotspot_info pointer" attr.style="top: {{towerPoint.posY}}%; left: {{towerPoint.posX}}%;" >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

import :

```
import {NgStyle} from '@angular/common';
```

set directive :

```
directives: [NgStyle]
```

then try:

```
<div class="hotspot_info pointer" [ngStyle]="{top: towerPoint.posY+'%'+; left: towerPoint.posX+'%'}" >
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `ngStyle` directive instead:

```
<div class="hotspot_info pointer"
   [ngStyle]="{top: towerPoint.posY + '%', left: towerPoint.posX + '%'}" >
```

Answer (score 0):

> The ngStyle directive allows you to set CSS style

```
<div class="ng-style: expression;"> ... </div>
```